# Is it possible to Increment/Decrement in php without using a variable?

Tags: php, numbers, increment, substr

For example: I have this code:

```
echo substr("1234567", -2, 1);
```

This will echo: 6

I want it to echo 7 (in that case), so i can do this:

```
$newvar = substr("1234567", -2, 1);
echo ++$newvar;
```

This will echo: 7

My problem is i have a lot of numbers to Increment, so i tried, for example:

`echo ++substr("1234567", -2, 1);` or `echo ++(substr("1234567", -2, 1));`

but that doesn't work. is it possible to some how increment the number without using a variable?

Comment: `echo substr("1234567", -2, 1) + 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to increment?

Try just adding 1, like `echo substr("1234567", -2, 1)+1;`

Comment: Works Great! Thanks!